# manage_[post_type]_posts_custom_column not passing `$post_id`

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress, I get the following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function processar_colunas_tc_events(), 1 passed in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 289 and exactly 2 expected`

... when I do this:

```
add_action('manage_tc_events_posts_custom_column', 'processar_colunas_tc_events');
function processar_colunas_tc_events($column, $post_id) { ... }
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Wordpress documentation for [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/).  There are four arguments into the function.  Note that the fourth argument is **`accepted_args`** and it specifies how many arguments your action accepts.  Since the default of **`accepted_args`** is 1 but your action accepts 2 arguments, you need to set **`accepted_args`** to 2.